# Pandas - Change alignment of dataframe

Tags: pandas

I've created a dataframe:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd 

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Student_ID':['001','002','003','004','005'],
                'Amy'   : ['Amy',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'Amy'],
                'Brian' : [np.nan,'Brian',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                'Cat'   : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'Cat',np.nan]},columns=['Student_ID','Amy','Brian','Cat']) 


In  [4]:df
Out [4]:
    Student_ID  Amy Brian   Cat
0          001  Amy   NaN   NaN
1          002  NaN Brian   NaN
2          003  NaN   NaN   NaN
3          004  NaN   NaN   Cat
4          005  Amy   NaN   NaN
```

And next I'd like to return to a dataframe with two columns only, Student_ID and Name.
How to convert to below in precise codes?

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
  Student_ID    Name    
0        001     Amy    
1        002   Brian    
2        003     NaN    
3        004     Cat
4        005     Amy
```

Answer (score 4):

You can using `dot`

```
df.iloc[:,1:].notna().dot(df.columns[1:])
Out[78]: 
0      Amy
1    Brian
2         
3      Cat
4      Amy
dtype: object
#df['name']=df.iloc[:,1:].notna().dot(df.columns[1:])
```

Or `bfill`

```
df.iloc[:,1:].bfill(1).iloc[:,0]
Out[82]: 
0      Amy
1    Brian
2      NaN
3      Cat
4      Amy
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `groupby/first`, since `first` selects the first non-NaN item in each group:

```
In [146]: df.set_index('Student_ID').unstack().groupby(level='Student_ID').first().rename('Name').reset_index()
Out[146]: 
  Student_ID   Name
0        001    Amy
1        002  Brian
2        003    NaN
3        004    Cat
4        005    Amy
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `.lookup`

```
df['Name'] = df.lookup(df.index, df.iloc[:, 1::].notnull().idxmax(1))

  Student_ID  Amy  Brian  Cat   Name
0        001  Amy    NaN  NaN    Amy
1        002  NaN  Brian  NaN  Brian
2        003  NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN
3        004  NaN    NaN  Cat    Cat
4        005  Amy    NaN  NaN    Amy
```